# Create a Json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am in process to validate a form where i need to show certain radio buttons and user need to select them based on some rules,how many number of radio buttons can be created is dynamic so i can not do validation on server side not can write a predefined java-script code for that.

each of the radio buttons will be divided in to groups say `required` and than further down they can be grouped like `center`,`left`, `right` etc, so from each group user need to select one value, so the structure comes out like this

```
-Main Group (if block needs to validate based on this e.g if key=required should validate)
  |
  Sub-group (say left, right etc)
   |
   number of radio buttons based on the sub-group
```

So the main group key can be used to decide if validation should be done on that or not and based on the sub-group key i can decide what all values will be there and needs to be validate

i was planning to create a JSON object on page rendering time like

```
{"required": [
        {"center": "id1,id2,id3"},
        {"left": "id1,id2,id3"}
      ]
  "optional": [
        {"center": "id1,id2,id3"},
        {"left": "id1,id2,id3"}
      ]
};
```

i am not sure if the structure i am thinking is right and how to create it in java script?
like i have a external loop for key and than one more loop for the sub-group and finally for the buttons in the sub-group,

```
 for(main group key){
     for(subgroup key){
       for(list of radio button under subgroup key)
}
  }
```

but not sure how to create a right structure so that i can parse it later with jquery and use that for validation.

Any help in this will really be appreciated.

Comment: JSON is `Javascript Object Notation`, so any JSON is just a native Javascript Object. In fact, most browsers include tools for manipulating JSON (check out the `JSON` namespace). To remotely load JSON, you should look into jQuery's `$.ajax` (namely, the `JSON` format option). With `$.ajax`, you can easily download JSON with jQuery, and then parse it in your callback function.

Comment: @neersighted:my problem is, i need to create this object on the jsp page itself and not on server side, i know about jquery json and ajax thing, but i need to create the JSON object on the Ui side.

Comment: Um, just create a new object? `var foo = {}`, `foo["bar"] = "baz"`. Or, if you want it to hold specfic information, check out [this](http://youtu.be/Bln9XbgbGrg) tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

In javascript. You can use  `JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);`

For example.

create on javascript object like this

```
var myObject={};
```

now after creating javascript object you can convert it into JSON structure like this

```
var myJsonText=JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

NOTE: replacer is optional

Now if you want to convert it in JSON Object Use JSON.parse method

```
myJsonObject=JSON.parse(myJsonText)
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs!!, but my question is more concerned about creating the structure as defined above

Comment: if i understood the question u need a form validator which contains radio buttons ?n ya you dono the number

Comment: if possible CAN you create a dummy structure of your form in jsfiddle?http://jsfiddle.net/